# React Native Expo How to add android permission with attributes

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to add this permission to `app.json`.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
                     android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
```

I don't know how to add the `usesPermissionFlags` attribute to it. What is the correct format to do so? Seems not documented on expo docs.

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "android": {
      "permissions": ["android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission in app.json like this:

```
{
"expo": {
  "android": {
  "permissions": ["BLUETOOTH_SCAN"]
    }
  }
}
```